# How to plot repeating stacked bar plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-chart

I am trying to plot a repeating color horizontal stacked bar plot. But I couldn't make it!

This my starting code:
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

```
dataset = [{'A':19, 'B':55},
           {'A':10, 'B':68}]
data_orders = [['B', 'A'],
               ['A', 'B']]
colors = ["green","blue"]
names = sorted(dataset[0].keys())
values = np.array([[data[name] for name in order] for data,order in 
zip(dataset, data_orders)])
lefts = np.insert(np.cumsum(values, axis=1),0,0, axis=1)[:, :-1]
orders = np.array(data_orders)
bottoms = np.arange(len(data_orders))

for name, color in zip(names, colors):
    idx = np.where(orders == name)
    value = values[idx]
    left = lefts[idx]
    plt.bar(left=left, height=0.8, width=value, bottom=bottoms,
            color=color, orientation="horizontal", label=name)
plt.legend(loc="best", bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.00))
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

But I want something like:
[image]

And want to provide a dataset with labels-values pairs and get the second output figure.

Maybe my code is a bad start! 
Any help will be very, very helpful! Thanks...

Comment: Your input dataset has 2 A and 2 B values, but your desired output has 4 bars for each. How are your data related to the desired graph?

Comment: It is just a random example, I even do not have any idea about using the correct data structure, but it should be something like (inner dims could be different): `dataset = [{'A':19, 'B':55, 'A':20},
           {'A':10, 'B':68, 'A':6, 'B':68}]`

Comment: You can think of it as a timeline which shows the active period of times of each player!

Comment: This can't be represented by a regular dictionary, which is unsorted and doesn't allow multiple occurrences of the same key.

Comment: What else you suggest?